# How to use two USB power banks

Tags: batteries, usb, comparator

I want to use two USB power banks for a camera to get longer battery life. Was thinking when the first one is drained, I would have a relay switching over to the other bank, using a comparator for example.
Does anyone here know at which voltage the switch-over should happen? Also, are there ICs or existing designs for this particular power/battery problem?

Thanks

Comment: `which voltage the switch-over should happen` .... at a voltage that is higher than the voltage at which the camera starts to fail

Comment: Beware that some power banks will shut off if they don't detect a load drawing current.  Other designs will not.

Comment: Chris That's a good point, thanks. Could maybe be solved by letting a small current bleed through a large resistor.

Comment: @MaSa - (a) When you reply to people, please don't just write (part of) their name. Instead, please prefix their name with "@" (matching names will usually be displayed in your browser after you type @ and a letter) so they get notified. Without that "@" prefix those users will not know that you replied, and so they might not reply again to you :-( (b) Your plan is not clear. From later comments, it seems like you might be planning to connect the 5V output from a USB power bank directly to a Li-Ion battery. Please edit the question and add more details, as they might change the advice you get.

Comment: @MaSa - Regarding comment replies using "@", see the explanation in this article on Meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Answer (score 0):

Use two schottky diodes, no switching needed. Whichever bank has the higher voltage will be the one supplying current.
With this diode for example, you would lose just 0.34V across the diode at currents up to 9A

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/smc-diode-solutions/95SQ015/1655-1922-1-ND/8021507

Each bank output to anode of a diode. Both cathodes connect together to feed the camera.  Connect all Grounds together.

Comment: That's a really nice solution. Do you have any idea if a camera would "care" about that voltage drop? The battery is Li 3.6V, there should be enough head room for the charging circuit, right?

Comment: BTW, I only need 1A, there are Schottky diodes with 220mV, that can't be a problem.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing more about the camera. Order a diode and try it,  it's a cheap experiment.  Batteries are near 4.2V when fully charged, dropping to 3.7V when discharged.

Comment: 0.34V was the lowest leaded part I saw here, 0.22V may be available in surface mount parts.  https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?k=schottky&k=&pkeyword=schottky&pv1989=0&pv69=80&FV=ffe00118&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Comment: There are ICs that perform this function using "ideal diodes". Look up for "PowerPath, Ideal Diodes & Load Switches"

Comment: @MaSa I strongly recommend following Ali Chen's advice.

Comment: Actually I ended up ordering both diodes and TPS2115APWR, just to be sure. Will use the IC, but if it fails for whatever reason I have the diodes as backup.

Comment: @MaSa Why do you care about the battery voltage? Aren't you expecting 5V from the power banks?

Comment: It may not charge if the voltage drop too much.

Comment: these have a 26mV forward drop https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/diodes-rectifiers-single/280?k=&pkeyword=&pv2261=u26mV+%40+8A&FV=ffe00118&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25

Comment: Elliot Yes, but there will be a voltage drop with diodes, but as I wrote, I ordered TPS2115APWR, which is like an "ideal diode" IC.